# Set two UIButton constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I am not able set constraints of two button next to each other. I need this two button in the middle of UIView. See below image[image]

can any know how to set these buttons constraints?

Answer (score 3):

Here I have set the constraint for the same:

1)Embed your buttons in UIView & set the constraint for that view.
[image]

2)Set constraint for first button
[image]

3)Set constraint for second button
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You DO NOT need to create an extra `UIView` to solve this problem!

From the [UILayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILayoutGuide_Class_Reference/index.html) docs:

> There are a number of costs associated with adding dummy views to your view hierarchy. First, there is the cost of creating and maintaining the view itself. Second, the dummy view is a full member of the view hierarchy, which means that it adds overhead to every task the hierarchy performs. Worst of all, the invisible dummy view can intercept messages that are intended for other views, causing problems that are very difficult to find.

You can use `UILayoutGuide`s to do this; instead of adding the buttons into an unnecessary `UIView`. You put a `UILayoutGuide` on the left and right sides of the buttons and set their widths to be equal. This will center the buttons. Here is how to do it in code:

```
view.addSubview(button1)
view.addSubview(button2)

let leftSpace = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(leftSpace)

let rightSpace = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(rightSpace)

let views = [
    "leftSpace" : leftSpace,
    "button1" : button1,
    "button2" : button2,
    "rightSpace" : rightSpace
]

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[leftSpace][button1]-[button2][rightSpace]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
leftSpace.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(rightSpace.widthAnchor).active = true
```

I have left out the vertical constraints since you are only concerned with centering them horizontally, but you will need vertical constraints. I'm sure something similar to this can be done in storyboards as well.

**EDIT for Objective-C**

```
[self.view addSubview:button1];
[self.view addSubview:button2];

UILayoutGuide *leftSpace = [[UILayoutGuide alloc] init];
[self.view addLayoutGuide:leftSpace];

UILayoutGuide *rightSpace = [[UILayoutGuide alloc] init];
[self.view addLayoutGuide:rightSpace];

NSDictionary* views = @{
                       @"leftSpace" : leftSpace,
                       @"button1" : button1,
                       @"button2" : button2,
                       @"rightSpace" : rightSpace
                         };

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[leftSpace][button1]-[button2][rightSpace]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[[leftSpace.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:rightSpace.widthAnchor] setActive:YES];
```

Comment: you are supposing he/she is using swift, but he/she didn't say anything about it

Comment: You can do the exact same thing in a slightly different syntax using Objective-C.

Comment: @ddb you should check out the question edit history. the question title said Swift before being edited by Eric

Comment: you're right, @Shubhank, I did not notice the question tag "swift" :)

Answer (score 2):

Select both buttons and embed these two buttons in UIView,
[image: embed UIView]
Horizontal Centre aligned UIView,
Set Width, height and Top Constrain for UIView.

you will get this :

[image]

**[Sample project for this](https://github.com/bilawal-liaqat/two-buttons)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do that :

- Define a horizontal spacing for your two buttons, let's say 10 for exemple
- Set center horizontally on the left button to the top view, and on this constraint set the multiplier to 1/2

(Don't forget the missing constraints such as top space between your button and the top view)

**EDIT** I do NOT recommend adding useless views as containers. This is bad practices. Multipliers are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

1. embed those 2 views in a view (in the designer, simply select the two views and then from xcode menu choose Editor -> Embed in -> View)
2. apply a constraint over the container view in order to center the view horizontally in the container
3. eventually, you can apply a top constraint over the container view between itself and the ViewController's view

Answer (score 0):

This is less information to work with, but you can add constraint programmatically to add the left space - x constraint to get to the middle of the page.
You can also get the two buttons in a small view which will make it easier to align in the middle

Comment: Use view is alternative option, I am looking for solution to set constraints. Can you show me the example to set constraint programmatically for these buttons. What else information you need?